# Extend root logical volume for VM with Oracle Linux of VMWare

Tags: virtual-machines, lvm, root

Please make me sure did I wrong thing, or not.

I'm resizing the root partition which is under the LVM. This server is a VMWare's virtual machine with Oracle Linux. I'm using this article: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006371

I think I made a mistake. After 2nd part I booted the VM in a rescue mode, checked that size was the same. Then I recreated 3rd partition (root under LVM) and gave its type as 8e for LVM. I received a partition with the same start point and extended last point. I wrote changes of frisk.

Then I executed `pvcreate /dev/sda3` command. It didn't allowed me to do this without -ff key.

So, I made a mistake and can't turn back. I didn't rebooted yet, I passed the system in rescue mode for a time.

Please give an advising is it possible to cancel this situation and make corrections?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had everything right, up until `pvcreate`. It's not necessary to do this if you resized the existing disk partition instead of creating a new one. If you actually ran it with the force flag, then it destroyed all your data. If you *did not*, then you are safe.

The next step, of course, is to restart the system and `lvextend -r` your desired logical volume. (`-r` here automatically resizes the filesystem in the logical volume, so you don't have to do that separately as the outdated KB article indicates.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I executed ``pvcreate`` with the force flag. :( But good news is that I experimented with the not important VM. I'm trying ``lvextend -L +250G -r -t -v /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root`` (the test run). As I see, pv wasn't extended: "fsadm: "ext4" filesystem found on "/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root". fsadm: Skipping filesystem check for device "/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root" as the filesystem is mounted on /. fsadm failed: 3. Extending logical volume lv_root to 291.68 GiB. Insufficient free space: 64000 extents needed, but only 0 available." Should I run ``pvextend``?

Comment: Oh, there is no ``pvextend`` command. ``pvscan`` shows this: PV /dev/sda2   VG VolGroup   lvm2 [49.51 GiB / 0    free]
Total: 1 [49.51 GiB] / in use: 1 [49.51 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]